# Git rebase hits "Out of memory, malloc failed" error

Tags: git

When I tried to rebase a repo:

```
git rebase XXX YYY
```

I get an "Out of memory, malloc failed" error:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 34537367 bytes)

git encountered an error while preparing the patches to replay
these revisions:

    3d5a7259c57b6b8a86fd6f7c44e6efa25a0e9db4..450ac9a6cf85475ab1a38b763f2f9a836a
4ba6a0

As a result, git cannot rebase them.
```

If I use cherry-pick it works without an error:

```
git checkout XXX
git cherry-pick YYY
```

I was using Git on Windows version 1.9.4-preview20140815. The machine has 8GB RAM, there is no file larger than 100MB in the repo, and the following are settings related with packing:

```
[core]
    packedGitWindowSize = 256m
    packedGitLimit = 256m

[pack]
    packSizeLimit = 2g
    threads = 2
    deltaCacheSize = 256m
    windowMemory = 256m
```

Comment: I know it's been almost an year, but have you ever found any other useful information about this? I am getting the same problem, and the reason looks like that we need more memory than the 32 bit git client can handle. So the logical thing would be installing a 64 bit client, but it's not easy, since I couldn't find it yet. It seems that you have to compile the git code using a 64 bit compiler, but still the git code doesn't seem to be prepared for 64 bit =( My only bet is that somehow the files or the branch need to be optimized so git can handle them

Answer (score 1):

First, 1.9.4-preview20140815 is not the latest git version any more. You can download the latest version [here](http://git-scm.com/download/win).

Also, if you believe Git is using more than 4GB of ram wihin Cygwin 32bits, you can switch to [Cygwin 64bits](http://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe)